# Equivalent of iwlist to see who is around?

Tags: wifi

What is the equivalent to:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

to see who (what computers and smartphones) are around me? Maybe putting the card into monitor mode before doing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also install the tool `fing` and do a network discovery using this tool. It [available as a RPM/DEB](http://www.overlooksoft.com/download), that you can just install standalone. The makers of this tool also make FingBox, which is a mobile application for doing the same thing.

#### Example

```
$ sudo fing
20:59:54 > Discovery profile: Default discovery profile
20:59:54 > Discovery class:   data-link (data-link layer)
20:59:54 > Discovery on:      192.168.1.0/24

20:59:55 > Discovery round starting.
20:59:55 > Host is up:   192.168.1.20
           HW Address:   00:26:C7:85:A7:20 (Intel)
           Hostname:     greeneggs.bubba.net
...
...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| State | Host                              | MAC Address       | Last change |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  UP   | 192.168.1.1                       | 00:18:51:4X:XX:XX |             |
|  UP   | 192.168.1.2                       | 00:25:22:1X:XX:XX |             |
|  UP   | 192.168.1.3                       | 00:19:D1:EX:XX:XX |             |
|  UP   | 192.168.1.4                       | 00:A0:CC:3X:XX:XX |             |
...
```

Don't let this tools simplicity fool you though. You can output the contents into csv files as well as html files:

```
$ sudo fing -n 192.168.1.0/24 -o table,html,blah.html
```

Then view it:

```
$ elinks blah.html
```

[image: ss of html]

To write out the results in CSV format:

```
$ sudo fing -o log,text log,csv,my-network-log.csv
```

To discover a specific block of IPs you can explicityly tell `fing` what IP block to scan:

```
$ sudo fing -n 192.168.1.0/24
```

#### Scanning wireless AP's

To see what IP's are on a given access point's (AP) network you have to actually be a participant on that network. You can however sit and passively listen to machines that are actively seeking out an access point. One tool that can assist with this endeavor is [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/).

*excerpt from [FAQ](http://www.kismetwireless.net/documentation.shtml)*

> 1. What is Kismet
>
> Kismet is an 802.11 wireless network detector, sniffer, and intrusion detection system.  Kismet will work with any wireless card which supports raw monitoring mode, and can sniff 802.11b, 802.11a, 802.11g, and 802.11n traffic (devices and drivers permitting).
>
> Kismet also sports a plugin architecture allowing for additional non-802.11 protocols to be decoded.
>
> Kismet identifies networks by passively collecting packets and detecting networks, which allows it to detect (and given time, expose the names of) hidden networks and the presence of non-beaconing networks via data traffic.

#### NetworkManager & scanning APs

As would make sense you can also scan for access points using NetworkManager. Actually it's doing this automatically when you use it to manage your network devices (specifically your WiFi device).

You can query NetworkManager via the command line (`nmcli`) and find out what access points are available.

```
$ nmcli -p dev wifi list
```

#### Example

```
$ nmcli -p dev wifi list
==========================================================================================================================
                                                      WiFi scan list
==========================================================================================================================
SSID                              BSSID               MODE             FREQ       RATE       SIGNAL   SECURITY   ACTIVE··
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'dlink'                           XX:24:XX:DA:XX:44   Infrastructure   2462 MHz   54 MB/s    31       WEP        no······
'ASUS'                            XX:AE:XX:E9:XX:33   Infrastructure   2462 MHz   54 MB/s    32       --         no······
'none_of_your_business_3'         XX:46:XX:47:XX:22   Infrastructure   2437 MHz   54 MB/s    81       WPA WPA2   yes·····
'none_of_your_business_1'         XX:22:XX:03:XX:11   Infrastructure   2437 MHz   54 MB/s    75       WPA WPA2   no······
'VR_Guest1'                       XX:46:XX:47:XX:00   Infrastructure   2437 MHz   54 MB/s    80       WPA WPA2   no······
```

#### References

- [fing users manual](http://www.overlooksoft.com/support)
- [Kismet Website](http://www.kismetwireless.net/)

Comment: @JosephR. - thanks, you're too kind 8-)

Comment: It's like `nmap` on steroids. I immediately downloaded the mobile version to my phone :)

Comment: @JosephR. - how's that version? Believe it or not, I don't own a smartphone 8-). I still think `nmap` is more versatile, but fing has it's places. When I'm at work our firewall will often times block me if I run nmap to see what IPs are on our network, fing doesn't suffer from this.

Comment: I haven't tried the CLI version yet, so I have no frame of reference. But it's a quantum leap compared to `nmap` from where I'm sitting. Not only is the formatting well polished, it's super fast, too. It can even send WakeOnLan packets!! My toolbelt thanks you :)

Comment: @JosephR. - yes the WOL and speed are the 2 real reasons I use it all the time. It's nice for waking systems up remotely using it. Has worked for all the systems I've tried it on thus far. If you wouldn't mind sharing after a while I'd appreciate any feedback on the mobile app, it looks like the best of the ones I've seen, but again I've never actually tried any of them so it's hard to say. I like to keep a list of tools to recommend to friends when they ask for such things.

Comment: Will do, hopefully :)

Comment: The tool is amazing, but there is one thing that I still need. If you got several APs around you, several devices, each connected to one of these APs, and you can connect only to one AP. How could you tell what other devices around (but not on your local network) you are doing? Or at least, make a list of all MACs of devices around you which are using some network (but not yours).

Comment: @QuoraFea - You have to be on the network in order to see the IPs that are "behind" a given AP. I believe that's what you're asking me, right?

Comment: OK, I see that you cannot know much about devices if you are not connected to a network. But using wireshark, I know that I could collect packages and analyze them and 'see' that MAC 'xx:yy:...' is connecting to network 'WLAN33'. I wonder if there is a command in fing (or other cl tool) that would let me 'see' what is happening in the wlans around me, what devices are connecting to what AP. Basically, what wifi traffic is flowing around me.

Comment: Take a look at Kismet: http://www.kismetwireless.net/. See my updates.

Comment: @slm The `fing` mobile app is amazing. Even my non (computer) techie friends at work see a benefit to it.

Answer (score 2):

In such situations, I usually do

```
nmap  192.168.x.0/24 > LAN_scan.txt
```

Where `x` should be replaced by your actual subnet. Also, `/24` is meant to represent the net mask. Modify according to your LAN settings.

This should perform a port scan on your local network. It will return a list of devices connected, which ports they have opened and which services they have on the open ports, etc...

`nmap` can sometimes identify the OS and the hardware vendor for hosts, too.

Also, the command line above is too simplistic: `nmap` has many knobs you can fiddle with; consult the man page.

Answer (score 1):

use aircrack-ng suit:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
sudo airodump-ng mon0
```

[image: output]

if you are in the same network: use nmap:

```
sudo nmap -sn gateway-ip/24
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution, is to ping the broadcast (if you have `192.168.0.N`) :

```
ping -b 192.168.0.255
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that streamlined user of Linux should use iw ;)

```
iw dev wlp7s0 scan
```

Also you can try horst:

```
iw dev wlp7s0 interface add mon0 type monitor
horst -i mon0
```

You may adapt to your wireless interface.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

My go-to tool for Wi-Fi analytics is the airomon-ng suite:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

And then

```
airodump-ng mon0
```

When you're done:

```
airmon-ng stop mon0
```

The cheapest, most inobtrusive way to get what you want, though, is to log into the AP and run:

```
iwlist ath0 peers
```

As an added benefit this will give you the upstream signal strength, as received by the AP, for each associated client.